# Whitespace created a start of HTML

Tags: templating, error, whitespace

I am getting a strange whitespace character when using a different language.

All languages use the same templates/database/plugins etc.
But when I go to any other language except the default I get a whitespace character before the

I have no idea what this is coming form. Its there when I disable all plugins and use a blank template.

[image: Screenshot of whitspace]

Comment: Maybe it's coming from the other language's public `index.php` files?

Comment: Afraid not, I have removed all trailing whitespace.

Comment: Found issue. The translation files were saved with encoding utf-8 with BOM

Comment: Ahh... nice catch!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally found what the problem was.

The translations files (/craft/translations/de.php) were encoded as "UTF-8 with BOM"
I opened these files in Sublime text and saved them as regular old UTF-8, which fixed the issue.